# Pesquisar conteúdo dentro das parâmetros da tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou criando uma barra de busca aonde o usuário vai digitando e vai filtrando em tempo real o conteúdo das `<li>`. Tenho um código parecido:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list-search-filter-map">
    <li><a href="">Conteudo 1</li>
    <li><a href="">Conteudo 2</li>
    <li><a href="">Conteudo 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function filterMap(element) {
            var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();

            $("#list-search-filter-map > li").each(function() {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Esse está funcionando como eu preciso, mas quero colocar um conteúdo dentro das tags `<a>` e ele também conseguir filtrar por eles. Então meu HTML ficaria mais ou menos assim:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list-search-filter-map">
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="São Paulo" data-estado="SP">Conteudo 1</li>
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="Rio de Janeiro" data-estado="RJ">Conteudo 2</li>
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="Curitiba" data-estado="PR">Conteudo 3</li>
</ul>
```

Ou seja, se o usuário também digitar `Rio de Janeiro` achará o **Conteúdo 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só trocar o `$(this).text()` por:

```
$(this).html()
```

Fica assim:

```js
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    filterMap(this);
});

function filterMap(element) {
  var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();

  $("#list-search-filter-map > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
    else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list-search-filter-map">
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="São Paulo" data-estado="SP">Conteudo 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="Rio de Janeiro" data-estado="RJ">Conteudo 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-cidade="Curitiba" data-estado="PR">Conteudo 3</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: Obrigado @JuniorNunes

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso precisas de mudar a lógica para:

```
if ($(this).find('a').data('cidade').toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
```

- `$(this).find('a')` vai buscar o elemento `<a>`
- `.data('cidade')` vai buscar o valor desse campo `data-`

```js
function filterMap(element) {
  var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();

  $("#list-search-filter-map > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('a').data('cidade').toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onKeyUp="filterMap(this)" />

<ul id="list-search-filter-map">
  <li><a href="" data-cidade="São Paulo" data-estado="SP">Conteudo 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-cidade="Rio de Janeiro" data-estado="RJ">Conteudo 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-cidade="Curitiba" data-estado="PR">Conteudo 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Acho que AP quer que filtre pelo data e pelo texto dentro do link @Sergio

Comment: @LucasCosta o AP escreveu _"Ou seja, se o usuário também digitar Rio de Janeiro achará o Conteúdo 2"_, daí esta sugestão.

Comment: "e ele também conseguir filtrar por eles".  Dessa forma se ele digitar Rio de Janeiro achará o Conteúdo 2, mas se Digitar Conteúdo 2 não achará nada

Comment: @LucasCosta ah, ok. Então nesse caso seria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/01ycfygj/ vou editar depois de saber melhor o que o AP quer.